# Make query after query with nodejs and sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, subquery, sequelize.js

I want to make a query after another query in node.js with sequqlize. Second query iterate ower the first elements query result.

The code:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  sqldb.sequelize.query("select * from food", {type: sqldb.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(function (food) {
        for (var i = food.length; i--;) {
          sqldb.sequelize.query("select     i.name_ingredient " +
            "from   food_incredients as fi, " +
            "ingredients as i " +
            "where  fi.food_id = " + food[i].id + " and " +
            "i.id = fi.ingredient_id;",
            {type: sqldb.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function (ingredients) {
            food[i]["ingredients"] = ingredients;
          });
        }

        res.status(200).json(food);
      }
    );
```

At the line when I try to add "infredients" field I reveive an error that the "food[i]" object is undefined. How can I fix this problem and return the "food" with ingredients for every elements?

Thanks